# hide right sidebar on specific pages in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I want to remove the sidebar from the specific page and all its subsequent pages in Drupal 7

My code is mention below.code is in mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) function

```
if ($variables['type'] === 'project'){
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if($node->type=='project'){
    //print_r($node);
        echo $node->type;
        unset($page['sidebar_second']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create a tpl file for that specific content type and remove the sidebar from there ? just an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try restricting the block in Blocks UI or with the [Context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context).

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict that sidebar content in admin panel itself. login as admin and configure that sidebar block to display only on perticular url.